# Single Page Apps vs PageAx

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

Single Page Apps are well known.  But PageAx seems to be less well known.  I stumbled across it by accident in learning MVC and it has worked quite well for me so far.

(Note: I am aware that this is a topic which may be regarded as "not answerable" and "should be closed" yet I feel this is an important topic which has not yet been covered.  Note that this is Single Page Apps vs. PageAx (not Ajax).  I am looking for benefits/disadvantage type discussion.  I am making up the name "PageAx" as I have not found a better term for it.)

SPA - communication with controller via Ajax and returning Json.

PageAx - communication with controller via Ajax and returning partial views which replace divisions.

Here are the benefits of PageAx as I see it, over SPA's:

1. Little to no JavaScript on the client.
2. I find Partial Views very easy to write on the server side.

Benefits of SPA over PageAx:

1. I can't think of any.

Disadvantages of PageAx over SPA:

1. Slightly larger payload (but I doubt it would be discernible by end user.)
2. I can't think of any other.

Disadvantages of SPA over PageAx:

1. Seems like the amount of JavaScript and required libraries present a fairly large learning curve (i.e., more so than MVC.)

So to re-iterate the question, are there any advantages to SPA over PageAx?  The basic reason for the question is that I am starting yet another web project and need to decide which way to take it.

Comment: Questions asking to recommend a tool or a framework or to make comparison between tools or frameworks are off-topic on StackOverflow. Your question will now be closed.

Comment: @Darin: This is not about tools & frameworks, this is about comparing approaches. Re-read the question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on complexity of your application.

Returning JSON is beneficial because hey—that means you have a full-fledged API that you can reuse in a mobile app or a desktop client. Even if you later decide to completely re-do your frontend, you will already have a ready-to-use backend to code against.

Also, if your webapp is highly dynamic and interactive, replacing partial views may not be enough. You may want to have finer control over transitions (e.g. animating them). For example, see [Medium-Style Page Transitions](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/30/medium-style-page-transition/): you can't do something like this with partial AJAX views.

On the other hand, if this flexibility doesn't buy you anything, rendering partial views on the server may work very well for you. Here's [David from 37signals blogging about it](https://37signals.com/svn/posts/3697-server-generated-javascript-responses). He calls this approach SJR (Server-generated JavaScript Responses):

> This doesn’t mean that there’s no place for generating JSON on the server and views on the client. We do that for the minority case where UI fidelity is very high and lots of view state is maintained, like our calendar. When that route is called for, we use Sam’s excellent Eco template system (think ERB for CoffeeScript).
>
> If your web application is all high-fidelity UI, it’s completely legit to go this route all the way. You’re paying a high price to buy yourself something fancy. No sweat. But if your application is more like Basecamp or Github or the majority of applications on the web that are proud of their document-based roots, then you really should embrace SJR with open arms.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.  My app is very much like Basecamp - more about data then about high UI fidelity.  So it sounds like partial Ajax views is the way to go.